# Dynamic Feature Navigation: Resource not found

Tags: android, android-navigation-graph, dynamic-feature-module

I am using a dynamic-feature module combined with a navigation graph. After going through the SplitInstall process (the dynamic feature is successfully installed), I attempt to navigate to a fragment in the dynamic-feature, but I am consistently getting a ResourceNotFoundException for my included navigation graph.

App Level Navigation Graph:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_app_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragment1">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.test.app.Fragment1"
        android:label="Fragment1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fragment1">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragment1_to_fragment2"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_module_two" />
    </fragment>

    <activity
        android:id="@+id/randomActivity"
        android:name="com.test.app.module_two.RandomActivity"
        android:label="RegistrationActivity"
        app:moduleName="module_two" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_registrationActivity"
        app:destination="@id/randomActivity" />

    <include-dynamic
        android:id="@+id/navigation_module_two"
        app:graphPackage="com.test.app.module_two"
        app:graphResName="navigation_module_two"
        app:moduleName="module_two"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fragment2">

        <argument
            android:name="aStringParam"
            android:defaultValue=""
            app:argType="string" />
    </include-dynamic>
</navigation>
```

Here is `navigation_module_two`:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentTwo"
    tools:ignore="UnusedNavigation">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentTwo"
        android:name="com.test.app.module_two.Fragment2"
        android:label="Fragment2"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fragment2">

        <argument
            android:name="aStringParam"
            android:defaultValue=""
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Here is the weird thing: I can navigate just fine to `RandomActivity` because it does not reference any resources (no associated XML layout). The problem is specifically when I try to navigate to `Fragment2` because it does have a layout.

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
2020-11-19 06:43:55.303 20550-20550/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.test.app, PID: 20550
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: com.test.app.module_two:navigation/navigation_module_two
    at androidx.navigation.dynamicfeatures.DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator.replaceWithIncludedNav(DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator.kt:95)
    at androidx.navigation.dynamicfeatures.DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator.navigate(DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator.kt:79)
    at androidx.navigation.dynamicfeatures.DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator.navigate(DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator.kt:40)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1049)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:935)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:868)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:854)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1107)
    at com.test.app.Fragment1$myHandlersListener$1.moveToNextFragment(Fragment1.kt:219)
    at com.test.app.databinding.NavigationDrawerBindingImpl._internalCallbackOnClick(NavigationDrawerBindingImpl.java:224)
    at com.test.app.generated.callback.OnClickListener.onClick(OnClickListener.java:11)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7869)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7838)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29362)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8125)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1:**

I should mention that if I build a universal APK (instead of an app bundle), this works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eventual solution was to place the contents of `navigation_module_two` inside of `navigation_app_graph` instead of using `<include-dynamic>`.

Comment: So your conclusion is that https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-dynamic is misleading because dynamic-features as it currently stands is broken?

Comment: @straya Not fully. The code I posted would work if the dynamic-feature was included at install time. It's specifically a problem when you launch it for the first time after calling for an install.